# How to exclude a set of packages from maven build jar?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

That's all I need. Additional details: I have a src/bootstrap/java folder and the regular src/main/java folder. Each one needs to go to a separate jar for obvious reasons. I was able to generate a bootstrap jar using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132958/ant-to-maven-multiple-build-targets):

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>only-bootstrap</id>
        <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>bootstrap</classifier>
          <includes>
            <include>sun/**/*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

But the regular jar still includes the bootstrap classes. I am compiling the bootstrap classes with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752972/how-to-add-an-extra-source-directory-for-maven-to-compile-and-include-in-the-bui).

Any light to generate a myproject.jar WITHOUT the bootstrap classes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You gotta use "default-jar" for the ID:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>only-bootstrap</id>
        <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>bootstrap</classifier>
          <includes>
            <include>sun/**/*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>sun/**/*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what command you have used to run specific execution id.

Comment: Thanks! What's the deal with having to specify `default-jar`? Does maven-jar-plugin look for it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can take a look at this before deciding to generate two jars from one pom.

[Maven best practice for generating multiple jars with different/filtered classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424015/maven-best-practice-for-generating-multiple-jars-with-different-filtered-classes)

If you still decide to get two jars, you can probably do it using this. You have to specify the proper exclusions.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>only-bootstrap</id>
            <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>only-library</classifier>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
              </includes>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/main*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>only-main</id>
            <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>everything</classifier>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
              </includes>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/bootstrap*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)?  It's what I use to strip out unused code.  It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880839/maven-proguard-and-assembly-issues) that you can add it as a Maven plugin.