# Include only certain packages in a Maven generated non-runnable jar

Tags: maven

I'm trying to build a non-executable jar file that only includes certain packages from my project to use as a library for common code. I'm planning on deploying that to Nexus and including it in other projects.

I can make it manually in eclipse by right clicking on the project, selecting Export, selecting JAR file (NOT Runnable Jar File) then checking the packages that I want to include. I'm trying to mimic this behavior in Maven. I have been able to replicate the non-runnable part in maven by not including a main in the manifest, but still have to find out how to include only certain packages.

This project actually builds 2 jar files already (from 2 different main's in the program - a test GUI and the regular application). I'm having trouble finding information on how to do the non-runnable jar and selecting certain packages only.

Here is the existing build portion of my pom file is below. Build-third is the non-runnable jar:

```
    <plugins>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-first</id>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.joy.fb20.da.exec.jDaExecutive</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>DaExecutive</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>build-second</id>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.joy.fb20.gui.jExampleAppGui</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>ExampleAppGui</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
<execution>
            <id>build-third</id>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>ddslib</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: How about separating that part as own artifact project and adding it as dependency to your original project? As well the others that need it?

Comment: I wanted to do that initially but the maintainer of the code refuses to split the source so my hands are tied in doing it in this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this myself and it is possible.

- Create a new maven profile
- Add `pluginManagement` section to that new profile for `maven-jar-plugin` and if needed for `maven-resources-plugin` also
- Use this `pluginManagement` to configure inclusions/exclusions of sources/resources and  override artifacts final name here to have different name for that separate jar

Example

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>subset</id>
      <build>
         <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.0.2</version>
                  <configuration>
                     <finalName>subset</finalName>
                     <includes>
                        <include>org/example/stuff/**</include>
                     </includes>
                  </configuration>
               </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </pluginManagement>
      </build>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

Using this profile maven creates `subset.jar` that has everything under `org/example/stuff/**`

See more about excluding: [How to exclude a set of packages from maven build jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753323/how-to-exclude-a-set-of-packages-from-maven-build-jar)

Of course it might be possible to do all this also without `pluginManagement` but in my opinion `pluginManagement` provides clean & flexible way to configure this kind of stuff so i recommend that.

Comment: I had to separate the original builds into a profile and the new one into its own profile and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that by using a custom assembly descriptor and specifying your fileset and / or file includes / excludes. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_fileSet

Comment: I tried doing this, by using exclude everything -> <exclude> * </exclude> and then including the packages I want and it seems like it just totally ignores these commands.